# VSTS: Xamarin sigining error

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using VSTS for Xamarin Android build.

During the signing step, its unable to find the location of .keystore file.

I saved it in the project directory.. //App.Droid/Development.keystore

File path in VSTS: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Development.keystore

**Error log**:

> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.1574541Z Set workingFolder to default:
> C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.100.1\tasks\AndroidSigning\1.0.19
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3474351Z ##[debug]agent.workFolder=C:\a
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3504349Z ##[debug]loading inputs and endpoints
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3514351Z ##[debug]loading
> ENDPOINT_AUTH_HTTPS://GITHUB.COM/**/**.GIT
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3514351Z ##[debug]loading
> ENDPOINT_AUTH_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3524350Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_FILES
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3524350Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_JARSIGN
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3534345Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_KEYPASS
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3534345Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_KEYSTOREALIAS
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3534345Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_KEYSTOREFILE
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3544350Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_KEYSTOREPASS
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3544350Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_ZIPALIGN
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3544350Z ##[debug]loaded 9
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3554349Z ##[debug]files=C:\a\1\b\Release*.apk
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3554349Z ##[debug]filesPattern:
> C:\a\1\b\Release*.apk
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3554349Z ##[debug]jarsign=true
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3564350Z ##[debug]jarsign: true
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3564350Z ##[debug]zipalign=true
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3564350Z ##[debug]zipalign: true
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3574349Z ##[debug]Matching glob pattern:
> C:\a\1\b\Release*.apk
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3574349Z ##[debug]Index of first wildcard: 17
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3574349Z ##[debug]find root dir: C:\a\1\b
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3644336Z ##[debug]find C:\a\1\b
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3644336Z ##[debug]87 matches.
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3714333Z ##[debug]process
> C:/a/1/b/Release/com.Myapp.apk
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3724335Z ##[debug]check path :
> C:/a/1/b/Release/com.Myapp.apk
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3724335Z
>
> ### [debug]JAVA_HOME=C:\java\jdk\jdk1.8.0_25
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3734336Z
>
> ### [debug]keystoreFile=C:\a\1\s\Development.keystore
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3734336Z ##[debug]keystoreAlias=Development
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3734336Z ##[debug]keystorePass=**password**
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3744327Z ##[debug]keyPass=**password**
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3744327Z ##[debug]jarsignerArguments=null
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3744327Z
>
> ### [debug]C:\java\jdk\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\jarsigner arg: ["-keystore","C:\a\1\s\Development.keystore"]
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3754328Z
>
> ### [debug]C:\java\jdk\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\jarsigner arg: ["-storepass","**password**"]
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3754328Z
>
> ### [debug]C:\java\jdk\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\jarsigner arg: ["-keypass","**password**"]
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3754328Z
>
> ### [debug]C:\java\jdk\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\jarsigner arg: ["-signedjar","C:/a/1/b/Release/com.Myapp.apk","C:/a/1/b/Release/com.Myapp.apk.unsigned","Development"]
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3764331Z ##[debug]exec tool:
> C:\java\jdk\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\jarsigner
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3764331Z ##[debug]Arguments:
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3764331Z ##[debug]   -keystore
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3774411Z ##[debug]   C:\a\1\s\Development.keystore
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3774411Z ##[debug]   -storepass
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3774411Z ##[debug]   **password**
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3784330Z ##[debug]   -keypass
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3784330Z ##[debug]   **password**
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3784330Z ##[debug]   -signedjar
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3794328Z ##[debug]
> C:/a/1/b/Release/com.Myapp.apk
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3794328Z ##[debug]
> C:/a/1/b/Release/com.Myapp.apk.unsigned
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3794328Z ##[debug]   Development
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:56.3804345Z
> [command]C:\java\jdk\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\jarsigner -keystore
> C:\a\1\s\Development.keystore -storepass **password** -keypass
> **password** -signedjar C:/a/1/b/Release/com.Myapp.apk C:/a/1/b/Release/com.Myapp.apk.unsigned Development
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:58.7576316Z jarsigner error:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load:
> C:\a\1\s\Development.keystore (The system cannot find the file
> specified)
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:58.7626300Z ##[debug]rc:1
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:58.7626300Z ##[debug]success:false
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:58.7636313Z ##[error]Error:
> C:\java\jdk\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\jarsigner failed with return code: 1
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:58.7656307Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
>
> 2016-06-06T18:45:58.7666308Z ##[error]Return code: 1

Can you please advise me how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the steps here to setup the signing for Android build: [Building Android Native and Cordova Android Projects](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/mobile/secure-certs#building-android-native-and-cordova-android-projects).